# Python: How do I select multiples that contain a specific number only?

Tags: python-3.x

For example, from all the multiples of the factor digit, I'd like to find the number of integers that have the digit "d" in one of the 2 digits of the integers. n is the limit to the number of multiples I'd like to search through.

```
def find_integers():
Factor=int(input("Enter Factor-digit:"))
d=int(input("Enter must-have-digit:"))
n=int(input("Enter the total number of integers:"))

for i in range(0,n):
    Multiples=(Factor*i)
```

How do I carry on to take out the multiples that have the digit "d" in them?

Comment: Please can you add the code you've already tried  ? and an example of what you expect exactly, there is *a lot* of multiples of 2

Comment: Ive added the code ive already tried. I apologise for the lack of specificity in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
multiples=[x*2 for x in range(0,1000000)]
# get 1 million multiples of 2
print(list(filter(lambda x:"4" in str(x),multiples)))
# this only prints the values in multiples if the lambda function returns true
# it only returns true if the string "4" is in the string representation of the number
```

I hope this helps